# how to import android class in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, base64, rsa

Good Evening
I am trying to import the android class by name"RSA.java" into Eclipse
but I have errors in these sections in `decode(key, Base64.DEFAULT) and encodeToString(key, Base64.DEFAULT)`  error is "DEFAULT cannot be resolved or is not a field" and `Base64.decode(MODULUS,0) and Base64.decode(EXPONENT,0)` 
error is "The method decode(String, int) is undefined for the type Base64"

```
public static byte[] decryptBASE64(String key) throws Exception {
        return Base64.decode(key, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

    public static String encryptBASE64(byte[] key) throws Exception {
        return Base64.encodeToString(key, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }
```

```
public static PublicKey getPublicKey(String MODULUS,String EXPONENT) throws Exception{
        byte[] modulusBytes = Base64.decode(MODULUS,0);
        byte[] exponentBytes = Base64.decode(EXPONENT,0);
```

My Android class imported into the Eclipse

```
package com.questdot.rsaexample;

import java.util.Base64;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;

public class RSA {
    public static final String KEY_ALGORITHM = "RSA";
    public static final String SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM = "SHA256withRSA";

    private static final String PUBLIC_KEY = "RSAPublicKey";
    private static final String PRIVATE_KEY = "RSAPrivateKey";

    public static byte[] decryptBASE64(String key) throws Exception {
        return Base64.decode(key, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }

    public static String encryptBASE64(byte[] key) throws Exception {
        return Base64.encodeToString(key, Base64.DEFAULT);
    }


    public static String sign(byte[] data, String privateKey) throws Exception {

        byte[] keyBytes = decryptBASE64(privateKey);

        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);

        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);

        PrivateKey priKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);

        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM);
        signature.initSign(priKey);
        signature.update(data);

        return encryptBASE64(signature.sign());
    }


    public static boolean verify(byte[] data, String publicKey, String sign)
            throws Exception {

        byte[] keyBytes = decryptBASE64(publicKey);

        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);

        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);

        PublicKey pubKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(keySpec);

        Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM);
        signature.initVerify(pubKey);
        signature.update(data);

        return signature.verify(decryptBASE64(sign));
    }


    public static byte[] decryptByPrivateKey(byte[] data, String key)
            throws Exception {

        byte[] keyBytes = decryptBASE64(key);


        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        Key privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(keyFactory.getAlgorithm());
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

        return cipher.doFinal(data);
    }


    public static byte[] decryptByPublicKey(byte[] data, String key)
            throws Exception {

        byte[] keyBytes = decryptBASE64(key);

        X509EncodedKeySpec x509KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        Key publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(x509KeySpec);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(keyFactory.getAlgorithm());
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

        return cipher.doFinal(data);
    }


    public static byte[] encryptByPublicKey(byte[] data, String key)
            throws Exception {

        byte[] keyBytes = decryptBASE64(key);

        X509EncodedKeySpec x509KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        Key publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(x509KeySpec);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(keyFactory.getAlgorithm());
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

        return cipher.doFinal(data);
    }


    public static byte[] encryptByPrivateKey(byte[] data, String key)
            throws Exception {

        byte[] keyBytes = decryptBASE64(key);

        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec pkcs8KeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        Key privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(pkcs8KeySpec);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(keyFactory.getAlgorithm());
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);

        return cipher.doFinal(data);
    }

    public static String getPrivateKey(Map<String, Object> keyMap)
            throws Exception {
        Key key = (Key) keyMap.get(PRIVATE_KEY);

        return encryptBASE64(key.getEncoded());
    }

    public static String getPublicKey(Map<String, Object> keyMap)
            throws Exception {
        Key key = (Key) keyMap.get(PUBLIC_KEY);

        return encryptBASE64(key.getEncoded());
    }


    public static Map<String, Object> initKey() throws Exception {
        KeyPairGenerator keyPairGen = KeyPairGenerator
                .getInstance(KEY_ALGORITHM);
        keyPairGen.initialize(1024);

        KeyPair keyPair = keyPairGen.generateKeyPair();

        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
        RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();

        Map<String, Object> keyMap = new HashMap<String, Object>(2);

        keyMap.put(PUBLIC_KEY, publicKey);
        keyMap.put(PRIVATE_KEY, privateKey);
        return keyMap;
    }

    public static PublicKey getPublicKey(String MODULUS,String EXPONENT) throws Exception{
        byte[] modulusBytes = Base64.decode(MODULUS,0);
        byte[] exponentBytes = Base64.decode(EXPONENT,0);

        BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(1, (modulusBytes) );
        BigInteger exponent = new BigInteger(1, (exponentBytes));

        RSAPublicKeySpec spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance(RSA.KEY_ALGORITHM);
        return kf.generatePublic(spec);
    }

    public static byte[] encrypt(Key publicKey, String s) throws Exception{
        byte[] byteData = s.getBytes();
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/PKCS1Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(byteData);


        return encryptedData;
    }

}
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: *...but I have errors ...* What errors? Edit your question to include the errors.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk /

for part 1) DEFAULT cannot be resolved or is not a field

/for part 2) The method decode(String, int) is undefined for the type Base64

Comment: There are two base64 classes in Android. In your code you are evidently using android.util.Base64 but you have imported java.util.Base64.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk
Yes you are right, because I want to use this code as a Java class in another program
And that's why I changed "android.util.Base64"  to "java.util.Base64", should I have used another method? Do you have a better suggestion?
Thanks